# BeautifulSoup Cannot Find Tag img

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, request, findall

Im trying to scrape the link of image from `url` https://www.eaton.com/us/en-us/skuPage.101012%2520G.html

All my solutions failed; here are my attempts:

1. ```py
   print(soup.select_one('[class="module-media-gallery__image lazyload"]')["src"])
   ```
2. ```py
   img=soup.find('img',attrs={'class':'module-media-gallery__image lazyload'})
   ```
3. ```py
   img=soup.find('img',class_='module-media-gallery__image lazyload')
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The image is lazily loaded; the `src` is not initially set. You can read the value from `data-src` instead.

```py
print(soup.select_one('.module-media-gallery__image.lazyload')['data-src'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked website and you have a typo error,
Image element has class with `module-media-gallery__image lazyloaded` not `module-media-gallery__image lazyload`

```html
<img class="module-media-gallery__image lazyloaded" alt="101012 G - Wireway systems and accessories" data-src="https://www.eaton.com/mdmfiles/PDM726777/4424G-C_R/500x500_72dpi" data-zoom-url="https://www.eaton.com/mdmfiles/PDM726777/4424G-C_R/1000x1000_300dpi"
  src="https://www.eaton.com/mdmfiles/PDM726777/4424G-C_R/500x500_72dpi" style="opacity: 1;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use such a solution using the get() method:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
        'accept': '*/*',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 YaBrowser/23.1.5.708 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36'
    }
link = "https://www.eaton.com/us/en-us/skuPage.101012%2520G.html"


session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update(headers)
response = session.get(link)
src = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
img=soup.find('img', 'module-media-gallery__image lazyload')
print(img.get('data-lazy'))
print(img.get('data-src'))
print(img.get('data-zoom-url'))
```

Result:

```
https://www.eaton.com/mdmfiles/PDM726777/4424G-C_R/500x500_72dpi
https://www.eaton.com/mdmfiles/PDM726777/4424G-C_R/500x500_72dpi
https://www.eaton.com/mdmfiles/PDM726777/4424G-C_R/1000x1000_300dpi
```